# Fetching values inside xml tags to csv

Tags: xml, csv

I have xml file with data in this format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<badges>
  <row Id="82946" UserId="3718" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.923" />
  <row Id="82947" UserId="994" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" />
  <row Id="82949" UserId="3893" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" />
</badges>
</xml>
```

How can i save it to a csv format this way--
3718,Teacher,2008-09-15T08:55:03.923
994,Teacher,2008-09-15T08:55:03.957

Comment: What's your technology stack of choice? No point in someone giving you a C# based answer if you're only comfortable with Ruby? Equally, a Ruby based answer would be useless to you if you're working with Java.

Comment: I am looking for something in python,java,perl or ruby

Comment: Someone has answered the question yesterday and it was correct, i am able to get the output using the R code that he posted. It will help others to solve this issue. But now i am not able to view the answer